# First and last value of window function in one row in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I'd like to have first value of one column and last value of second column in one row for a specified partition. For that I created this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
b.machine_id,
batch,
timestamp_sta,
timestamp_stp,
FIRST_VALUE(timestamp_sta) OVER w AS batch_start,
LAST_VALUE(timestamp_stp) OVER w AS batch_end
FROM db_data.sta_stp AS a
JOIN db_data.ll_lu AS b
ON a.ll_lu_id=b.id
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY batch, machine_id ORDER BY timestamp_sta)
ORDER BY timestamp_sta, batch, machine_id;
```

But as you can see in the image, returned data in batch_end column are not correct.

*batch_start* column has correct first value of *timestamp_sta* column. However *batch_end* should be "2012-09-17 10:49:45" and it equals *timestamp_stp* from same row.

Why is it so?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question is old, but this solution is simpler and faster than what's been posted so far:

```
SELECT b.machine_id
     , batch
     , timestamp_sta
     , timestamp_stp
     , min(timestamp_sta) OVER w AS batch_start
     , max(timestamp_stp) OVER w AS batch_end
FROM   db_data.sta_stp a
JOIN   db_data.ll_lu   b ON a.ll_lu_id = b.id
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY batch, b.machine_id) -- No ORDER BY !
ORDER  BY timestamp_sta, batch, machine_id; -- why this ORDER BY?
```

If you add **`ORDER BY`** to the window frame definition, each next row with a greater `ORDER BY` expression has a later frame start. Neither `min()` nor `first_value()` can return the "first" timestamp for the whole partition then. Without `ORDER BY` all rows of the same partition are **peers** and you get your desired result.

Your added `ORDER BY` *works* (not the one in the window frame definition, the outer one), but doesn't seem to make sense and makes the query more expensive. You should probably use an `ORDER BY` clause that agrees with your window frame definition to avoid additional sort cost:

```
... 
ORDER BY batch, b.machine_id, timestamp_sta, timestamp_stp;
```

I don't see the need for `DISTINCT` in this query. You could just add it if you actually need it. Or `DISTINCT ON ()`. But then the `ORDER BY` clause becomes even more relevant. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

If you need some other column(s) from the same row (while still sorting by timestamps), your idea with `FIRST_VALUE()` and `LAST_VALUE()` might be the way to go. You'd probably need to append this to the window frame definition *then*:

```
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
```

See:

- [PostgreSQL query with max and min date plus associated id per row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9800/3684)

Answer (score 8):

The explanations given by @Łukasz Kamiński solve the core of the issue.

However, the `last_value` should be replaced by `max()`. You are sorting by `timestamp_sta` so the last value is the one having the greatest `timestamp_sta`, which may or may not be related to `timestamp_stp`. Also I would sort by the two fields.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  b.machine_id,
  batch,
  timestamp_sta,
  timestamp_stp,
  FIRST_VALUE(timestamp_sta) OVER w AS batch_start,
  MAX(timestamp_stp) OVER w AS batch_end
FROM db_data.sta_stp AS a
JOIN db_data.ll_lu AS b
ON a.ll_lu_id=b.id
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY batch, machine_id 
             ORDER BY timestamp_sta,timestamp_stp 
             RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
ORDER BY timestamp_sta, batch, machine_id;
```

http://rextester.com/UTDE60342

Comment: While this should work, it is needlessly complicated and expensive. I added an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

From [syntax documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS):

> The frame_clause specifies the set of rows constituting the window frame, which is a subset of the current partition, for those window functions that act on the frame instead of the whole partition. The frame can be specified in either RANGE or ROWS mode; in either case, it runs from the frame_start to the frame_end. **If frame_end is omitted, it defaults to CURRENT ROW**.
>
> A frame_start of UNBOUNDED PRECEDING means that the frame starts with the first row of the partition, and similarly a frame_end of UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING means that the frame ends with the last row of the partition.

and [function list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html)

> last_value(value any)     returns value evaluated at the row that is the **last row of the window frame**

So correct SQL should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
b.machine_id,
batch,
timestamp_sta,
timestamp_stp,
FIRST_VALUE(timestamp_sta) OVER w AS batch_start,
LAST_VALUE(timestamp_stp) OVER w AS batch_end
FROM db_data.sta_stp AS a
JOIN db_data.ll_lu AS b
ON a.ll_lu_id=b.id
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY batch, machine_id ORDER BY timestamp_sta range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
ORDER BY timestamp_sta, batch, machine_id;
```

Comment: Great, that's it! I've just discovered this manual page, too, but I still didn't fully understand how it works. Thanks for working example.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think it returns the expected result.

Comment: @klin Yes, it did for me. What's wrong with this solution?

Comment: See the note in the @JGH answer.

Comment: It wouldn't work if you had concurrent inserts (or other reason to get different sort for those 2 columns) on that table and for batch your last _started_ insert would end before some other one in said batch. So it would be last started, not last finished, but `last_value()` would still return this row value, not actually last finished in batch.

Comment: You have `ORDER BY timestamp_sta` in the window frame definition. Does not work for `LAST_VALUE(timestamp_stp)`. Note: `timestamp_stp`<> `timestamp_sta`. Easy to overlook.