# Reusing the same moving window for multiple window functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table of numbers in a Postgres database, and I'm trying to calculate the range (max-min) of the 3 preceding and 3 following rows, for each row.
Given a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table AS (
SELECT
    generate_series(1,100) id,
    random()*generate_series(1,100) val
);
```

This can be done with the following query:

```
SELECT
    id,
    MAX(val) OVER (
        ORDER BY id
        ROWS
            BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING
            AND 3 FOLLOWING
    ) - 
    MIN(val) OVER (
        ORDER BY id
        ROWS
            BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING
            AND 3 FOLLOWING
    ) val_range
FROM test_table;
```

But the `OVER` clause is duplicated. Is there a way to improve the query and remove the duplicate? Would the duplicate impact performance? How should I handle the moving window if I wanted to calculate other aggregates for each id?

I've come up with the following query to reuse the window, but I'm not sure if it's the optimal approach.

```
WITH
windowed AS (
SELECT
    id,
    UNNEST(ARRAY_AGG(val) OVER (
        ORDER BY id
        ROWS
            BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING
            AND 3 FOLLOWING
    )) val
FROM test_table
)
SELECT
    id,
    MAX(val)-MIN(val) val_range,
    AVG(val) val_mean,
    STDDEV(val) val_stddev
FROM windowed
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`WINDOW` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#%22SQL-WINDOW) to shorten your code:

```
SELECT id
     , MAX(val) OVER w - 
       MIN(val) OVER w AS val_range
FROM   test_table
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 3 FOLLOWING);
```

But that hardly affects performance at all. Postgres will reuse the window frame if you spell it out repeatedly as well. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-WINDOW)

> When multiple window functions are used, all the window functions
> having syntactically equivalent `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses
> in their window definitions are guaranteed to be evaluated in a single
> pass over the data.

Related:

- [How to use a ring data structure in window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030179/how-to-use-a-ring-data-structure-in-window-functions/25039137#25039137)
- [First and last value of window function in one row in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368672/first-and-last-value-of-window-function-in-one-row-in-postgresql/51457588#51457588)

Comment: That makes sense! Is `WINDOW a` supposed to be `WINDOW w`?

Comment: Is it generally true that using `SELECT...WINDOW...` is only syntactic sugar? Can it even improve performance?

Comment: @LondonRob: Yes. The `WINDOW` clause is solely a "convenience feature" in Postgres, so you can reuse window definitions in multiple `OVER` clauses of window functions. I added a quote from the manual.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually an important extra piece of information about windows: you don't need to worry about specifying the same window many times, the query planner will sort it all out and only calculate each window once!