# Get time ranges in Postgres, based on separate column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, range

I am trying to get start/end date or timerange from table, based on status of a certain column.

Imagine having the following structure :

```
          date          | flag 
------------------------+------
 2023-08-06 23:35:00+00 | t
 2023-08-06 23:36:00+00 | t
 2023-08-06 23:37:00+00 | t
 2023-08-06 23:38:00+00 | f
 2023-08-06 23:39:00+00 | f
 2023-08-06 23:40:00+00 | f
 2023-08-06 23:41:00+00 | f
 2023-08-06 23:42:00+00 | t
 2023-08-06 23:43:00+00 | t
 2023-08-06 23:44:00+00 | t
```

I would like to get the following as an output :

```
          start         |          end           | flag 
------------------------+------------------------+------
 2023-08-06 23:35:00+00 | 2023-08-06 23:37:00+00 | t
 2023-08-06 23:38:00+00 | 2023-08-06 23:41:00+00 | f
 2023-08-06 23:42:00+00 | 2023-08-06 23:44:00+00 | t
```

Having start and end time, where flag was in a certain status (or have certain value). How could I achieve that ?

Comment: It looks to me like you need a windowing function and you want to get the first and last row of each window. Maybe this will help? [First and last value of window function in one row in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44368672/first-and-last-value-of-window-function-in-one-row-in-postgresql)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the start and end datetime ranges based on the column status, you can try this query;

```
SELECT
  MIN(date) AS start,
  MAX(date) AS end,
  flag
FROM (
  SELECT
    date,
    flag,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date)
    - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY flag ORDER BY date) AS grp
  FROM your_table_name
) subquery
GROUP BY flag, grp
ORDER BY start;
```

The query identifies the rows with the same status and then determines the time intervals where the status remained constant.